# Can't separate string using sscanf?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a text file of associated numbers i.e;
1 2 2
3 2 1
3 4 3

Each line is a seperate piece of information, as such I am trying to read it in one line at a time and then seperate it into the 3 numbers but sscanf isn't doing what I expect it to.

```
char s[5];
char e[5];
char line[100];
int d;

fgets(line, sizeof(line), inFile);
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d", s, e, d);
```

putting in a printf after fgets yeilds:
1 2 2

but then after sscanf, the variables 's' and 'e' are null while 'd' is some random number that I can't even figure out where it's come from.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read this: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seperate . This and all the other entries. It will save you from making speeches on "priviledge seperation" in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure how a dictionary definition of "seperate" will assist me in programming? Also take note that we both spelt separate wrong.

Comment: I didn't spell separate wrong, dude. You should also take classes on sarcasm. I was attempting to prevent you from looking like an idiot savant once you become a great programmer. FYI, most web browsers nowadays include support for a spell checker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We really need to see your variable declarations, but in the case of d you should definitely be passing the address:

```
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d", s, e, &d);
```

From your comment, it seems you are not declaring the strings correctly. You want something like:

```
char s[10], e[10];
```

depending on how big you expect the strings to be. But you must specify a size. The `line` variable should be declared similarly.

Comment: ok fair enough, that's a dumb mistake.
i've tried declaring s and e as char s, char e or as char s[], char e[], neither seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Trent How about char s[10], e[10];

Comment: @Trent Well, you need to post more code. Please do this by editing your original question.

Comment: ok scratch that, i think i have it sorted now, forgot to add in the address of d.
Thanks Neil